# Remove the comment "Generated by Javadoc on <date> <time>" in generated Javadoc

Tags: html, version-control, javadoc

A javadoc command automatically inserts a comment stating something like:

```
<!-- Generated by javadoc (build 1.6.0_17) on Thu Apr 07 18:32:31 CEST 2011 -->
```

in every generated HTML file.

This is quite preventing change tracking for versioned javadoc, since every file will be modified when regenerating the doc.

A previous question I asked convince me not to version any javadoc, but it also raised this problem and the question remains: is there a way to get rid of this comment? I did not find trace of such possibility in the javadoc options.

Comment: Have you looked at this bug?: http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=5025224

Comment: I can't find more info on this and it does not work...

Comment: @JackMc: If you add an answer similar to mine, I'll delete my answer and upvote yours. This is too important to be hidden in a comment.

Comment: @Paulo nice from you.. And I agree actually. Although you added some precision, so you can leave your answer and i will upvote it too ;) Once i have fresh votes to cast. However this __-notimestamp__ thing does not work for me although I think my JRE is up-to-date

Comment: @Dunaril: does it simply ignore the option, still adding the comments (it is the comment shown in your question, isn't it?), or do you get some error message?

Comment: Are you sure that 1. you are looking at the documentation just generated (compare the timestamp in the documentation with the current time), 2. you are really executing the command with the option? Try to start from the command line, if you were using an IDE or ant or such before.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Thank to JackMc's comment, I found the command line parameter `-notimestamp`. It works (at least for my 1.6.0_20 here).

If using ant, you'll have to add it to the `<javadoc>` task using either the `<arg value="-notimestamp" />` nested element or an `additionalparam="-notimestamp"` attribute.

(I just [used this](https://github.com/ePaul/jsch-documentation/commit/674cab5bed7a386ce5a8b44fe1b57fd493157715) for my github-managed [JSch documentation.](http://epaul.github.com/jsch-documentation/javadoc/).)

Comment: For me, this only shortens the message to "Generated by javadoc (21)", which is still annoying, because firstly I do not need it and secondly it does not produce reproducible builds, because it still prints the javadoc version used.

Comment: I don't remember whether this version number was already there 13 years ago when I wrote the answer. I'd suppose when the javadoc version changes, you'd get a different output formatting anyways, so this part would not be the biggest problem.

Comment: I created an OpenJDK bug for making this configurable anyway, because the version number in the message is hard-coded . As soon as it has been accepted, I can add a link here. BTW, the javadoc format changes occasionally with new JDKs, but far less frequent than you might imagine. Otherwise, I would have to adjust certain tests in some of my project every 6 months, which I do not need to do. I.e., I can in many cases create identical javadocs with different JDKs. There are also options to e.g. create Java 8 javadocs in JDK 21. That can make sense if reproducible builds are important.

Comment: BTW, I know that your answer is 13 years old, but it is still valuable, so I figured I should add some more value by commenting on this detail.